# Search params not preserved on page refresh when using permission.ui module

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-permission

I'm using **angular 1.5.8**, **angular-ui-router 0.2.18** & **5.1.0** version of [anglar-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission) library. I have enabled the HTML5 mode in the app.

Everything was working fine in my app until today when I starting making use of `$location.search()` method.

My module is including dependencies as:

```
angular.app('app', [
    ...
   'ui.router',
   'permission', 'permission.ui', 
   ...
]);
```

I have a simple user listing page with various filters. I'm changing the app so that whenever filter changes, I set it on the URL (so that the user can share the URL with applied filters). For example, `$location.search({query: 'john', sort: 'email'})`. This is working fine and the URL is getting changed from http://localhost:9000/user/list to http://localhost:9000/user/list?query=john&sort=email when any filter is applied.

But when I'm refreshing the page or opening the URL with the query string in a new tab, the query params are getting removed and URL is being changed back to http://localhost:9000/user/list. I have been searching the cause for this issue for the whole day and went through various GitHub issues of Angular, ui-router and other SO posts but nothing helped me.

Then I started trial & error and removed this library module completely and things started working fine. I researched more and found out that it's actually the `permission.ui` module that is causing this problem so if I just remove the `permission.ui` module from the app, that query string persists on refreshing the page.

I don't understand how the `permission.ui` module is making that issue and what is the fix for that.

**Update 1**

Here is my state configuration (not really sure if this matters in my issue):

```
var adminPermissions = {
    only: 'ROLE_ADMIN',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard'
};

$stateProvider
    .state('loggedIn', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/layouts/logged-in.html'
    })
    .state('user', {
        parent: 'loggedIn',
        abstract: true,
        url: '/user',
        data: {permissions: adminPermissions},
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('user.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'views/user/list.html'
    });
```

GitHub issue [#401](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission/issues/401)

Comment: if you use permission.ui, than    redirectTo properties you need to add for params

Comment: I didn't get you @Ved I already have `redirectTo` property for my state then what needs to be done?

Comment: can you update your route code here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Ved. Updated my question with state code.